# VB.net Decimal to Hex conversion

Tags: vb.net

I am using the code below to convert decimal to hex.

intPatternColorsRed(1)=255 I get "FF" which is good

intPatternColorsRed(1)=0 I get "0" but I need "00"

Can I format the output to use a placeholder so I alway get a 2 digit return

```
'//Convert Dec to Hex
strData(0) = intPatternColorsRed(1).ToString("x")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strData(0) = intPatternColorsRed(1).ToString("X2")
```

ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx